# What will be a good choice for storing chrome app data locally among IndexedDB and File System?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, indexeddb, html5-filesystem

I am trying to develop a chrome app which will store data. Data storing will be unlimited. I have two options to use Indexed DB and File System.

Which would be a good choice for data storage among the above two

Comment: What type of data? There is also [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)

Comment: data like any webapp uses in general, like records in table, multimedia wherever required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using File System API to store data in the user PC is a bit problematic because you can't do it without the user approval. So my suggestion is to use indexedDB with the following permissions in your manifest:

```
"permissions": [
   "unlimitedStorage",
   "storage"
]
```

Basicly you can store anything in indexedDB the only problem with it its a bit slow and the API is a mess but there are lots of tutorials out there. I use it by myself for an offline first app. Its a bit hard to use but reliable way to store persistent data.

Another thing worth to note if you want to store key value pairs like settings for your app you can use chrome storage API with is the basic local storage API but chrome app exlusive.

Useful reading: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps

Comment: In answer you mentioned that the indexed db is slow. Is it very slow to be noticeable. can indexdb store images and multimedia ? and any best wrapper you would suggest for indexed db for chrome apps?

Comment: Its not extraordinary slow but noticeable. For an example i created an app. During the app startup the server sent a 80 mb sized array of objects to the client trought websocket which took 4 sec then i stored this array to indexeddb which took 6 sec. Its not that bad actually. Its only noticeable if you want to store lots of data but you can use a webworker for this task.
See benchmark: [link](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDB/perf/)
 
Yes you can store images and media as blobs. There are tutorials out there for this.

Comment: When i started using indexedDB i was looking for a good wrapper but i did not found any suiting my needs so i created one myself. Its not a big deal just create functions to store data, store bulk data, truncate object storage etc. add some error handling and you are done, not more than 500 lines of code. But there are lots of wrappers out there, even good ones. My main problem with them is these projects are no longer maintened and i don't like 4 years old unmaintaned code.